# Removing words after a symbol is detected

Tags: java, regex, comments

How do I remove words from a text file that have symbols preceding them?

For example:

```
This is important information...  //but this is a comment
This is more important info...  //and this is another comment
```

How do I remove the words along with the symbol "//but this is a comment" ?

Here's my pseudocode:

```
1. If "//" is detected, line.replace "//" symbol
2. Clear the words after the symbol 
3. Go on to the next line till you see "//" symbol
4. Repeat steps 1-3 (loop).
```

Note: this is occurring while the file is being read:

```
String line;
while ((line = textReader.readLine()) != null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that given:

```
This is important information...  //but this is a comment
This is more important info...  //and this is another comment
```

You want:

```
This is important information...
This is more important info...
```

Something like this should work:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("//.*$", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

line = matcher.replaceFirst("");
```

`Pattern` is what Java uses for regular expressions. Here's [some information](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) about Java regular expressions in Java. The regex I've used looks for two forward slashes and everything after that until the end of the line. Then, the text that is matched is replaced by an empty string. `Pattern.DOTALL` tells Java to treat `^` and `$` as beginning and end-of-line markers.

**EDIT**

This code below demonstrates how it works:

```
import java.util.regex.*; 

public class RemoveComments { 

   public static void main(String[] args){ 

      String[] lines = {"This is important information...  //but this is a comment", "This is more important info...  //and this is another comment"}; 
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("//.*$", Pattern.DOTALL); 

      for(String line : lines) { 
          Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line); 

          System.out.println("Original: " + line); 
          line = matcher.replaceFirst(""); 

          System.out.println("New: " + line); 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: `Pattern` is what you use in Java to handle regular expressions.

Comment: OK, I got it. I have to import those classes.

Comment: @rudna1010 Yup, `java.util.regex` has those classes.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! I've never used regular expression before, but now I know :)

Comment: @rudna1010 They are useful and powerful, but don't be seduced by their power :) Sometimes they are more trouble than they are worth.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing an idea, you could play around with the functions of String

first locate the charaters that removes

```
int i = indexOf('//', 0);
```

Then look for the index of the next space

```
secondIndex = indexOf(' ',i);
```

then you can extract both side

```
String s1 = subString(0,i);

String s2 = subString(secondIndex,i);

String res = s1+s2;
```

This is not optimal but should get the job done ^^

Comment: Reading the answer of Vivin, it might be simpler to use the regex like he showed you (not so strong on regex :P)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to do a regular expression replacement in one line:

```
line = line.replaceAll("//.*$", "");
```